# Redirecting all but one pattern of file to new site

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

If I have http://example.com and I want to redirect all traffic except orange.1.php, orange.2.php, orange.32.5.php, etc to http://newexample.com, how would I write the .htaccess? Just to be clear, http://example.com/blah should redirect to http://newexample.com, not to http://newexample.com/blah. I've googled for an hour trying different things, and none seem to work.

I thought this should work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^orange\.[0-9]+.*$
RewriteRule ^/?.*$ "http:\/\/newexample\.com" [R=301,L]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`REQUEST_URI` always starts with a forward slash.

You can use this refactored shorter rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^orange\.\d+\.php$ http://newexample.com/? [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: Make sure this is first rule and you completely clear browser cache.